# How to use Angular pattern validator on FormControl multiple times with different error message

Tags: angular

I am developing reset password form, where I want to validate the password field with some validation. Validations are mentioned below:

1. 1 Character Uppercase.
2. 1 Character LowerCase.
3. Minimum Length should be 8.
4. Max Length of 10.

Here is my component code as per need.

```js
this.userForm = this.appFormBuilder.group({
  password:['',[Validators.pattern(/[a-z]/),Validators.pattern(/[A-Z]/), Validators.min(8),Validators.max(10)]]
})
```

I want to show error message of respective condition has been failed on UI, But I am getting pattern error object on UI. How can I show error message of respective condition failed.
Here is my Html code:

```js
<div [formGroup]="userForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="password" />
  {{userForm.controls.password.errors | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error message from specific validation name.

Ex :

```
<div [formGroup]="userForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="password" />
  {{userForm.controls.password.errors. pattern}}
  <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.min">Min length should be 8</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.max">Min length should be 10</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.pattern">Pasword format must be xyz format</div>
</div>
```

> Multiple errors with the same error (e.g.: 'pattern') will be override.

So if you want to use same pattern validator you should write the custom `validator`.

```
 regexValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      if (!control.value) {
        return null;
      }
      const valid = regex.test(control.value);
      return valid ? null : error;
    };
  }
```

-

```
 this.regexValidator(new RegExp('[a-z]'), {'smallLetters': ''}),
 this.regexValidator(new RegExp('[A-Z]'), {'capitalLetters': ''})
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="r.firstName.hasError('precision')">It must have small letter </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I show the Uppercase and lowercase message.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an function which will validate the form control

```
export function validatPatternMatch(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean}  {
  const age = control.value;
  if(condition1 fails){
    return {lowercase: true};
  }else if(condition2 fails){
    return {uppercase: true};
  }
  return null; // no error
}

this.userForm = this.appFormBuilder.group({
  password:['',[validatPatternMatch]]
});

<div [formGroup]="userForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="password" />
   {{userForm.controls.password.errors. pattern}}
  <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors?.lowercase">One Lowercase</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors?.uppercase">One Uppercase</div>
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will try and let you know